# Hide toolbar layout lines

Tags: android, xml

I have a UI design to create where the toolbar is immersed within the recyclerview.
I have created the design but the lines of the layout are still visible on device whereas it appears to be right in the emulator. How do I merge the layout line in recyclerview.

Below is a screenshot from emulator

[image]

and below is a screenshot from my device
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="80"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"

                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

That line is a shadow, caused by the Toolbar's *elevation*. Elevation only happens automatically on devices running Lollipop or newer, and the layout preview often doesn't show shadows.

Try adding this attribute to your Toolbar's XML to remove the elevation (and therefore the shadow):

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

The most concise answer and easiest way to remove hide ToolBar Layout line/divider adding this line in your style.xml file inside the AppTheme style or whatever theme style you declared for your activity:

```
<item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
```

then your  should look something like this

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    ...
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <!-- This line is not compulsory -->
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
     <!-- This line is not compulsory -->
    ...
</style>
```

I hope this helps. it worked for me tho
Result: here's a screenshot of a typical example:[image]